# Not able to restart animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to restart css animation when contents of div is changed. I have tried all method i can find googling none of them seems to work. I have tried

> JQUERY

```
$("p1").removeClass("content");
$("p1").addClass("content");
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
var elm = this,
var newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
```

and some other methods like setting display to none and then block or changing animationName

Here is my code

> HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="content" id="p1">
        <div class="person"></div>
        <img src="img/saying.png" class="statusclound"/>
        <p class="status"></p>
        <img class="frame" src="img/splash_1.png" id="frame_1"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            display: none;

            animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-direction: alternate;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

@keyframes buzz-out {
            10% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
                transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
            }
            20% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
                transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
            }
            30% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
                transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
            }
            40% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
                transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
            }
            50% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
                transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
            }
            60% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
                transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
            }
            70% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
                transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
            }
            80% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
                transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
            }
            90% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0deg);
                transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0deg);
            }
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0deg);
                transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0deg);
            }
        }
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
function test() {
        var currentPatch = document.getElementById("p" + patchTurn);           

        currentPatch.getElementsByClassName("person")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url(http://localhost:80/slingshot/uploads/" + jsonData[3] + ")";
        currentPatch.getElementsByClassName("status")[0].innerHTML = jsonData[2];
        currentPatch.getElementsByClassName("frame")[0].src = "img/splash_" + randomFrame + ".png";
        currentPatch.style.animationName = "buzz-out";
        currentPatch.style.display = "block";
    }
```

So when the page loads div is disabled and `test()` function runs and div animates but when i change some content inside that div and re-run `test()` function it doesn't animate.

Comment: You're not actually toggling the class in `test()`...is that intentional?

Comment: Also can we see the `buzz-out` animation code?

Comment: @aeolingamenfel i removed toggling class code as it was not working... and i have updated question with buzz-out animation code

Comment: Thanks. Can you whip up a JS fiddle *with* the class toggling code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too clear on what part you need help with so I've made a working JSfiddle that shows all of it working.

I created an event listener for changes in the div and adds the class "content-active" to the div. This class adds the animation name and sets the display to block. Then the class is removed and re-added to restart the animation. To get the animation to restart, I set a 10ms delay. (You can also clone the div if you'd like)

https://jsfiddle.net/heraldo/zyjuoLt1/

JS:

```
// watch for changes in the DOM
$('#content').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    // clear any previous animation
    $("#p1").removeClass("content-active");
  // setting a timeout allows the animation to restart
  // NOTE, you can also clone the element and re-add it to do
  // the same thing.
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#p1").addClass("content-active"); }, 10);
});

// simply adds text to the status <p>
$('#modify').click(function(){
    $(".person").append('text ');
});
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.content-active{
  display: block;
  animation-name: buzzOut;
}



@keyframes buzzOut {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translateX(1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- simply adds text to the div -->
<button id="modify">Add Text</button> 

<div id="content">
  <div class="content" id="p1">
    <div class="person"></div>
    <p class="status"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this works for you!